# Create files in my shell script owned by root without the need for sudo

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

This might seem a little strange question at first but here me out.

I'm writing a shell script that makes up a file system that'll get compressed back into an archive and it needs some files in it to be owned by the root user.  This whole thing is going to be automated soon but right now it's a bit of a problem because if I use sudo I need to enter in a password.

Seeing as the files are created beneath my own home directory for which I have full access I thought perhaps I can change their ownership to a root user.  Is that possible?

If I try it normally I get "Operation not permitted".  Maybe there is an alternative?

Comment: You can use `su` or `sudo`, but that's about the end of it.  You can't create files belonging to someone else, least of all `root`, as an ordinary user.  Your best bet might be to modify the archiving tool to change the recorded permissions on the files within the archive.

Comment: You are root user or sudoers?

Comment: hmm. Maybe I can do it with schroot

Comment: fakeroot is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want using [fakeroot](http://man.he.net/man1/fakeroot). It's a library that makes programs *think* they're running as root, when they are not. IIRC, it is used by `dpkg` to allow non-root users to build `.deb` packages that contain root-owned files.

Check out this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir image
touch image/user-owned
touch image/root-owned

chown renato.renato image/user-owned
chown root.root     image/root-owned

tar cf image.tar image
```

Normally, I would only be able to create this tar archive as root. However, if I use fakeroot:

```
$ fakeroot ./create-image.sh
$ tar tvf image.tar

drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2014-04-09 01:09 image/
-rw-r--r-- root/root         0 2014-04-09 01:09 image/root-owned
-rw-r--r-- renato/renato     0 2014-04-09 01:09 image/user-owned
```

However, the files on the disk are still user-owned, so no security risk here:

```
$ ls -l image/

total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 renato renato 0 Abr  9 01:09 root-owned
-rw-r--r-- 1 renato renato 0 Abr  9 01:09 user-owned
```

Comment: ahh, now you're onto something... I recall this command from long ago.  That's why I asked the question as I thought such a tool existed.